# "AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application" when signing in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-webapp) to create an app that uses the Microsoft Graph API, and I'm getting the following error when I click the "sign in with Microsoft" button:

> AADSTS50011: The reply url specified in the request does not match the reply urls configured for the application: (the guid that is my application ID)

I added several URLs to the list of redirect URLs for my app at the Azure app configuration portal - one for another web app I want to eventually integrate this with (http://localhost:31503), one that was listed in the tutorial (http://localhost:44368), and the one that IIS Express is running the tutorial app as (http://localhost:7360). Even after adding all these URLs, though, I still get this error - what could be going on? Why can't I sign in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a mistake in this tutorial. You should add `https://localhost:44368/` on Azure portal, not `http://localhost:44368/`.

By the way, for the mismatch issue, there is a common solution. Just like @Marc said, you can track the auth request url to find the redirect_uri parameter. The request url is something like

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/authorize? client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e &response_type=code &redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345 &response_mode=query &resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F &state=12345
```

After clicking sign in button and before inputting the account, you will find the request url.

[image]

Comment: Aha, the `"s"` in `"https"` did it - thanks so much! I did see the `redirect_uri` parameter, but it was URL-encoded so it was kind of hard for me to read...

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the url your application is sending to AAD to request login. It will include url encoded reply_url parameter. Decode it and make sure your application is registered with exactly the same url: same casing, no extra/missing trailing slashes.

Comment: It's `redirect_uri` not reply_url

Comment: It is reply_url